# Loading Tensorflow model in different sessions yields incorrect results

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a TF model that's trained for sentiment analysis. After I compile and fit the model, save it, then load it in another notebook session, locally or in colab, the model predicts nowhere near the accuracy I get. I assume it is because of the tokenizer. I defined the tokenizer, called the fit_on_texts method on the training data, converted to sequences and applied the padding then passed the output to the model. When I have to predict on new text, I have to do the same process again but this time, define a different tokenizer and that yields random results.

This is how I create my tokenizer:

```
tokenizer = text.Tokenizer() 
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text)
text_tokenized = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
X_text = sequence.pad_sequences(text_tokenized, maxlen=MAXLEN)
```

A solution I tried is pickling the main tokenizer object then loading it back in other sessions and using it on the predicted text. That works. But I was wondering if there's something more convenient. Maybe adding the main tokenizer as a layer in the model itself, if that's possible? I tried researching for a solution but came up short.

Comment: Can you share complete code to replicate  your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I just went with the pickling the tokenizer object. I tried adding a TextVectorization layer to the model but I had a few issues with it.